# Suitable mechanism to relate json data to database?

Tags: database, django, database-design

So im working on a side project involving the Steam API and I am not sure if this would be a suitable and effective way to do what I want.

Basically I have a User model with an inventory field relating to a certain game. I fetch the Users game inventory when they log-in and store the json result within this single field. I have another model which contains the item schema for every item in the game.

Basically I want to relate the information stored within the database for a particular item(item model) to that items information within the json result(inventory items).

I previously tried to save the inventory in a separate table and created a relation between the user, user-inventory and items in this table however the problem with this was ensuring that the inventory stored in my database was the same as that fetched (exactly identical). Under this scenario I would basically need to delete(multiples may exists of the same item) every inventory item and then insert the inventory items retrieved at login back in.

My question is this. Is this an appropriate solution, bad practice or is there a better way to do what i need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have to delete *all* of the inventory items and re-add the new ones? Could you iterate through each of the inventory entries and add/update/delete as needed?

I think that the JSON solution would work. It's probably a matter of preference at this point. I always feel like it's nicer to stay with a traditional relational data structure until you really need to optimize. But I don't see why the json wouldn't work. You can create a utility function on your user model that extracts the item ids and fetches all of the related records.

Comment: I see, well I have decided to go with having a separate table for users inventory and then just deleting all records (for a user) and reinserting them on login (i may change this later on). However, I just wanted to find out if constantly deleting and inserting hundreds of rows will degrade performance of the database over time? The reason I ask is because the primary key field auto increments after a deletion so I assume the ID's in relation to the rows may still be stored somewhere?

Comment: Constant deletes and updates might fragment your database. If you are using postgresql you could vacuum it by setting autovacuum as 1 which could help you overcome the fragmentation.